# Центрирование нескрываемого текста в мобильной навигации

Tags: css, bootstrap, navigationbar

Используется bootstrap 3. Код навигации:

```
<div class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top" id="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <p class="navbar-text visible-xs-inline-block"><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/mobile-logo.jpg"></a> <a href="tel:+1111111"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/tel.png"> +1111111</a></p>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="topnav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/">главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/about-us/">о нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/projects/">работы</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/offers/">услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/price/">цены</a></li>
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/tel.png"> +1111111</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Смысл в том, чтобы вывести это на плашку в мобильной версии навигации:

```
<p class="navbar-text visible-xs-inline-block"><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/mobile-logo.jpg"></a> <a href="tel:+1111111"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/tel.png"> +1111111</a></p>
```

Оно выводиться, но не выходит отцентрировать содержимое плашки. То есть выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо выровнять телефон по центру. Если сделать для p width:100% кнопка раскрытия меню справа сползает вниз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Bootstrap есть [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Можно ею воспользоваться.

**1.** В вашем скриншоте есть оранжевый квадрат слева. Если он присутствует в дизайне, то можно сделать три колонки и текст в колонке с телефоном отцентрировать посередине, добавив бутстраповские классы для отрисовки сетки на мобильных устройствах - .col-xs-

Так как класс visible-xs-inline-block делает элемент блочно-инлайновым и он больше не занимает всю ширину блока, то в стилях ширину нужно добавить.

После этого центрировать внутреннюю ссылку, сделав ее блочным элементом и добавив выравнивание текста по центру.

```css
.navbar-text{
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-text a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-toggle{
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 2px #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top" id="top-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <p>Я оранжевый квадрат</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <p class="navbar-text visible-xs-inline-block"><a href="tel:+1111111"><img
                            src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/tel.png"> +1111111</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="topnav">
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/">главная</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/about-us/">о нас</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/projects/">работы</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/offers/">услуги</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/price/">цены</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/tel.png">
                        +1111111</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2.** Если оранжевого квадрата нет в дизайне, то можно сделать две колонки и колонку с телефоном подвинуть вправо с помощью bootstrap класса [col-xs-offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

```css
.navbar-text {
  width: 100%
}
.navbar-text a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top" id="top-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
          <p class="navbar-text visible-xs-inline-block"><a href="tel:+1111111"><img
                            src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/tel.png"> +1111111</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="topnav">
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/">главная</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/about-us/">о нас</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/projects/">работы</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/offers/">услуги</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/price/">цены</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/tel.png">
                        +1111111</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отказаться от бутстрапа в своих проектах до тех пор, пока не освоите хотя бы азы `css`. Как только вы начнете понимать в данной сфере определенный минимум, в частности то, что ваш `p` итак должен растягиваться на всю ему дозволенную ширину, вы сами поймете, что намного проще все сделать самостоятельно. И не придется прибегать к использованию инструментов, которые изначально придуманы не для новичков. В следствие чего и вопросов вы таких непрофессиональных задавать не будете, и отвечать вам быстрее и содержательнее станут.

Comment: По вашему, bootstrap надо изучать в лабораторных условий? Ответ выше содержателен и по делу. Ваш ответ разве что тешит ваше же самолюбие.

Comment: Мой ответ содержателен, но @mJeevas прав. По вашему вопросу видно, что вы еще "плаваете" в обычной верстке. Вы должны понимать, что layout страницы - это сетка, которая должна поместиться в 100% ширину. Если бы вы это понимали, то предложения "Если сделать для p width:100% кнопка раскрытия меню справа сползает вниз." не было бы. Естественно кнопка сползет, потому что ей не хватит места...
И подтянуть знания о блочных и инлайновых элементах, в частности почему в вашем случае блочный элемент p не занял изначально 100% ширины.
P.S. И совет: не хамите в комментариях, вам перестанут давать ответы.